# Android Toolbar to appear at the bottom of the screen instead of the top

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

I am trying to set a toolbar at the bottom of the screen after an event but the toolbar is tied to the top of the screen. Any idea how do i set it to be at the bottom of the screen ?

```
    app:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarmenucontainer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            android:text="test" />



        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            android:text="test2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Toolbar is just like any other ViewGroup. Wrap it inside a RelativeLayout and align it to parent bottom.

Comment: can you post the complete xml layout code??

Answer (score 0):

Android toolbar is the new Action Bar. It’s not bound to any activity, meaning **it can be placed anywhere in the layout**, is highly customize-able and can be used as an “Action Bar”.

[image: Android toolbar at the bottom]

Details with the code [here](http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-toolbar-example/)

XML Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ahotbrew.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_brew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps but it is still at the top instead of at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity.xml

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:alignParentBotton="true"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_normal" />
```

And **toolbar_normal.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:background="@color/yourcolor"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tittle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"



                android:text="tittle"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />


      <--customise your toolbar here -- >

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in **Manifest.xml** Apply theme to your activity

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Now if you want to set tittle in java use

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    tittle= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tittle);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Simply where you are including `toolbar.xml` put it inside `RelativeLayout` as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.erginus.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```